# Image (img) tag in html causing container grid-area to extend

Tags: html, css

I'm starting out in HTML/CSS and I'm looking at using grids (grid-template-areas).  I have the layout how I like it, and the top left grid-area is for my site logo.  The issue I'm having is that when I add an  tag to the html, it causes the container to grow.  I've attached images to show what I mean.  The strange thing is it isn't growing by the same width as the image, so there seems to be some kind of offset going on that I don't know how to stop.

UPDATE:  I realised this isn't an issue with the img tag, as even adding text into the .logo grid area causes the same issue.

[image]

Note how the width of the container seems to grow by about 50% of the image width.  I don't know why this is happening.  I've tried adding different properties to the img{} in the stylesheet, as well as the container, but nothing seems to resolve it.

Any ideas or suggestions on where to look would be great.  I've spent some time searching but all the results are teaching you how to grow/shrink/align your image vs stopping it messing with the container.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="media/images/centrecircle.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="header">
        <h1>KickBallLife</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="leftNav">Left Nav</div>

    <div class="content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

    <div class="rightWidget">Widget</div>

    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
{
box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {

}



/* The grid container */
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:    'logo   header  header  header  header  header' 
                            'left   middle  middle  middle  middle  right' 
                            'footer footer  footer  footer  footer  footer';
    /* grid-column-gap: 10px; - if you want gap between the columns */
}

.leftNav,
.content,
.rightWidget {
    padding: 10px;
}

.header {
    grid-area: header;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    height: 100px;
}

.logo {
    grid-area: logo;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    height: 100px;
}

.leftNav {
    grid-area: left;
    background-color:lightblue;
}

.content {
    grid-area: middle;
    background-color:darkblue;
}

.rightWidget {
    grid-area: right;
    background-color:aquamarine;
}

.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    background-color:coral;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}


@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .grid-container {
        grid-template-areas:    'logo   logo    logo    logo    logo    logo' 
                                'header header  header  header  header  header' 
                                'left   left    left    left    left    left' 
                                'middle middle  middle  middle  middle  middle' 
                                'right  right   right   right   right   right' 
                                'footer footer  footer  footer  footer  footer';
}
```

I don't know if this is relevant, but the actual html is within an .aspx master page.

Thanks in advance,

Terry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out.  I needed to use the grid-template-columns property to set the widths of each column.  What threw me was I'd tried it previously but had comma separated the values, when it should just be space separated like so:

```
grid-template-columns: 15% 17.5% 17.5% 17.5% 17.5% 15%;
```

So the container would be:

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 15% 17.5% 17.5% 17.5% 17.5% 15%;
    grid-template-areas: 'logo   header  header  header  header  header' 'left   middle  middle  middle  middle  right' 'footer footer  footer  footer  footer  footer';
}
```

Thanks for the suggestions and starting points all!

Terry

Answer (score 0):

Set a width on the .logo in your css.

```
{
box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {

}



/* The grid container */
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:    'logo   header  header  header  header  header' 
                            'left   middle  middle  middle  middle  right' 
                            'footer footer  footer  footer  footer  footer';
    /* grid-column-gap: 10px; - if you want gap between the columns */
}

.leftNav,
.content,
.rightWidget {
    padding: 10px;
}

.header {
    grid-area: header;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    height: 100px;
}

.logo {
    grid-area: logo;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px; /* Change to whatever width works with your image*/
}

.leftNav {
    grid-area: left;
    background-color:lightblue;
}

.content {
    grid-area: middle;
    background-color:darkblue;
}

.rightWidget {
    grid-area: right;
    background-color:aquamarine;
}

.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    background-color:coral;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}


@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .grid-container {
        grid-template-areas:    'logo   logo    logo    logo    logo    logo' 
                                'header header  header  header  header  header' 
                                'left   left    left    left    left    left' 
                                'middle middle  middle  middle  middle  middle' 
                                'right  right   right   right   right   right' 
                                'footer footer  footer  footer  footer  footer';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried this, and it does resize the logo area, but that knocks it out of whack with the rest of the grid i.e. the Left Nav area below it stays the same width and it causes a gap between the logo area and the KickBallLife header section.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, comment-out or remove the first 3 lines of your CSS code. Either that or figure out which element selector you are trying to set the `border-sizing` attribute on. Without a selector on line 1 the rest of your CSS will be buggy.

Second, you need a width set on the parent container to prevent the logo, or any other content, from blowing up your grid.

I’ll also have to admit, CSS Grids was a tricky concept to learn myself. I mean, understanding FlexBox was tough but CSS Grids is a whole another step more complex. Further, there are still issues with current browsers regarding your ability to get them to render CSS Grids consistently.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I tried that too, but adding the width to the .logo parent container just makes the grid fail to stay equal.  The grid area shrinks to the width I specify but I don't want it to do that, I want the grid template to decide the width of the grid area, but the image to reside within it, without causing resizing of the parent.